# why to i have to cast NSMutableArray to NSMutableArray?

Tags: swift, casting

In my function arguments I declared that `files` argument has to be of type `NSMutableArray`. Why does Xcode then say that the `files` argument is of typ `AnyObject` and I have to cast it to `NSMutableArray`?

```
internal func downloadMultiple(files: NSMutableArray, remoteBaseUrl: NSURL, completion: (result: Int)->()) -> Void {
    self.filesToDownload = files.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray // why this cast necessary?
    self.cb = completion

    for item in files {
        print("file ", item["file"] as! String)
        self.download(remoteBaseUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(item["file"] as! String)!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're still using NSMutableArray instead of the Swift array syntax?

Comment: @Bob Not really i'm new to all this ios stuff and had to quickly get something running, without reading a lot first. :( As soon as i get some time I will read, learn and rewrite everything cleanly.

Comment: Don't use NSArray in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mutableCopy` is implemented by NSObject and defined as:

```
func mutableCopy() -> Any
```

So therefore when you call `mutableCopy()` the resulting object needs to be cast.